# Seperate robots.txt for non-www domain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, robots.txt

I found an .htaccess code that can render different robots.txt for ssl response like the one below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots-deny-all.txt [L]
```

Trying what I found above will not work and I cant find a way to tweak it. What I need is render separate robots.txt for non-www request. For example I want www.example.com/robots.txt for www request and example.com/nonwww-robots.txt for non-www request.

I hope there is a way I can do this because I can't find any solution online.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? If you want to prevent non-www urls (or www urls) from being crawled, why not redirect those requests?

Comment: i have spam links coming from .ru website, i want return 404 from refer and block the url before google starts crawling them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots-deny-all.txt [L]
```